# Browserstack loading Cookie policy window twice

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I'm running my tests in Browserstack via nightwatchjs.

The test runs Ok locally, but when I run then in Browserstack I get the following error message;

[image]

looking into this further, it appears that this error is related to the fact that the Cookie Policy window is actually loaded twice when the test is run in Browserstack (and the correct once locally).

So when I run my test, it's clicking on the first "Accept all", but then the same window is loaded again.

My cookie policy dismissal looks like this;

````
```exports.command = function() {
    var cookiePolicy;
    this.element('css selector', '#sp_message_iframe_117586', function(result) {
        cookiePolicy = result.value;
        this.frame(cookiePolicy, function() {
            this.elements('css selector', 'button.message-component.message-button.no-children', function(cookie) {
                if (cookie.value.length != 0) {
                    this.click('button.message-component.message-button.no-children');
                    this.frameParent();
                } else {
                    console.log('cookie policy already agreed');
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
````

I'm just wondering if there's another way to stop the cookie policy from being displayed in the first place, or another way to dismiss the cookie policy window (twice!) or a way to stop Browserstack from loading it twice?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such capability or method in selenium to accept all the cookies, you will have to handle the same using click method, before performing click make sure you verify if it is in another frame. 
Following are few selenium cookies method:
driver.manage().getCookies();   // Return The List of all Cookies
driver.manage().getCookieNamed(arg0);  //Return specific cookie according to name
driver.manage().addCookie(arg0);   //Create and add the cookie
driver.manage().deleteCookie(arg0);  // Delete specific cookie
driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed(arg0); // Delete specific cookie according Name
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();  // Delete all cookies